# iOS app in portrait & landscape only for iPhone 6+/7+

Tags: ios, iphone, orientation

How can I set my project configuration to allow my app to work in both portrait and landscape on iPhone 6+ & 7+ models and other iPhone models has to support only Portrait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[use this third party lib for detecting the running device's model and screen size.](https://github.com/sebyddd/SDVersion)

//AppDelegate.h

```
@property () BOOL restrictRotation;
```

//AppDelegate.m

## import "AppDelegate.h"

## import "SDVersion.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 // Check for device model
if ([SDiOSVersion deviceVersion] == iPhone7Plus){
    NSLog(@"You got the iPhone 7. Nice!");
  restrictRotation=YES;
}
else if ([SDiOSVersion deviceVersion] == iPhone6SPlus){
    NSLog(@"You got the iPhone 6S Plus. Awesome device!");
   restrictRotation=YES;
}


 return YES;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask )application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if(self.restrictRotation)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    else
    {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    
}
```